# customView doesn't match parent height and width

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-windowmanager

**summary:**

Hello
I'm trying to cover a custom inflated view above another view,
for most the devices it works fine and the custom view covers the whole view,
but for some reason in devices with screen size 5.7 it doesn't.
[here is an example how it looks like for Nexus 6p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5KDq.jpg)

**the problem:**
for devices with screen size 5.7 the custom view doesn't match parent height and width.

**code:**

```
  private void addCustomView(){

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        MyCustomView myCustomView = (MyCustomView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view_layout, null);

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mWindowManager.addView(myCustomView, getLayoutParams());

    }

    private WindowManager.LayoutParams getLayoutParams(){
        if (mParentView == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int[] array = new int[2];
        mParentView.getLocationOnScreen(array);

        //Build Params
        int width = mParentView.getWidth();
        int height = mParentView.getHeight();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        mWindowParams.x = array[0];
        mWindowParams.y = array[1];

        mWindowParams.height = height;
        mWindowParams.width = width;

        mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED;
        mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        mWindowParams.windowAnimations = 0;

        return mWindowParams;
    }
```

**MyCustomView XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.app.myapp.MyCustomView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                   
                android:visibility="invisible">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</com.app.myapp.MyCustomView>
```

Comment: MyCustomView extends a RelativeLayout, the purpose of this class is to handle the inner web view logic, loading URL's, click listeners and etc. there is no UI manipulation...

Comment: The custom view is used as a container for the web view and more content in the future, refactoring this right now is impossible.

Comment: I'm adding the custom view using a window manager, it must be on the top of the views hierarchy. also, I need "getLayoutParams" method to calculate where to place the view.                          mWindowManager.addView(myCustomView, getLayoutParams());